# how to set dependent width of a dropdown in bootstrap

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have an easy bootstrap dropdown menu. but it is much wider than parent menu item selection. how can I do it the same width as it's parent menu item to look like a solid block?

Answer (score 0):

you can override the width style by apply the inline style to the Menu options.
where you are applying class to your options, just add an inline `style = "width: 250px"`
set the width to whatever you want.

In this way only your width will be override and you can adjust it according to your own need.

Comment: I thought about getting width of parent item with jquery and then set dropdown's width dynamically... but I hoped there is away to do it with css rule